# Why there is a run time error in this python program?

Tags: python

I have C++ background and very new to Python. I might be making a simple mistake.

```
def make_polish(s) :
    no_of_pluses = 0
    polish_str = []
    i = 0
    for index in range(len(s)):
        print s[index]
        if '+' == s[index]:
            no_of_pluses = no_of_pluses + 1
        if '*' == s[index]:
            polish_str[i] = s[index-1] """Index out of range error here."""
            i = i + 1 
            polish_str[i] = s[index+1]
            i = i + 1
            polish_str[i] = '*'
            i = i + 1

    return polish_str 

print make_polish("3*4")
```

Comment: Can you please reformat the code so it's copy-pasteable into a Python REPL.

Comment: Please edit your code so that it has more consistent indentation. Also, mixing tabs and spaces is a very bad idea in python

Comment: Please suggest a light weight Python editor for windows.  I used notepad++ for it.

Comment: @qqqqq Try [PyScripter](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your list `polish_str` is always empty. You need to do:

```
polish_str.append(s[index-1])
```

Instead of:

```
polish_str[i] = s[index-1] # """Index out of range error here."""
i = i + 1
```

When you create the list `polish_str = []` it's not allocating space for it as it does in C/C++. It's a dynamic data structure.

Comment: Thansk it worked. It seems it is a linked list and  I have to do a hidden "new" of C++.